# Oracle quartz selectWithLockSQL value?

Tags: java, oracle, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have this in my spring config for quartz....

```
<prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL">SELECT * 
                                                    FROM {0} LOCKS WITH (UPDLOCK ROWLOCK) 
                                                   WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?</prop>`
```

That works fine for MS SQL Server, but I don't know what to use for Oracle.

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: The Spring/Quartz parts of this aren't really relavent, it's a question about how to rephrase a given bit of SQLServer-specific SQL for Oracle. I suggest you make your question specific to that, and remove the java/quartz/spring parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so what are you trying to do there?  the syntax in Oracle to lock a row is:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <condition> FOR UPDATE;
```

Comment: I think this is the correct value...
<prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL">SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS WHERE LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE</prop>

Comment: @jeff porter's comment is worked for quartz 1.8.3 and if i use quartz 1.6.1 it is not necessary to give that property